# 3 layer application non networked?

Tags: oracle, networking, listener, virtualization, openldap

I have a system named Windchill which runs in a CentOS 5.7 virtualbox;
The system consists of apache, oracle 11g, listener, windchillDS(openLDAP) and the application core (method server) which is a java process. All installed in the same vm(monolithic)

My question is related with the network, The system runs smooth on the network, but once I remove the network cable it stops working and the method server keeps restarting with the socket timeout error.

Im not a IT specialist, I manage the internal configuration of the system and I dont have an specialist to help me right now but I need **desperately** to make it run non networked in a laptop to show it for a customer.
I just want a hint of where may be the problem:
Does oracle runs non networked? Which configurations do I need to make it run without a network?
Maybe the problem is the listener?
I guess the problem is the oracle because of the socket timeout error with the database but Im not sure...

Sorry this is long and probably needs more explanation, please ask whathever you want!

Comment: you want a locally running database (on your laptop) I assume?  Why not connect to your network remotely via vpn?

Comment: I will be out in the customer and I will not have internet access there, even my pendrives can't get inside the building due to security rules... I need it completely non networked or only with host/guest network...

Comment: I think what you need is a loopback adapter, "a testing tool for a virtual network environment where network access is not available".  I'm afraid that's about the limit of my knowledge ;)

Comment: I think its a bit unreasonable to expect any significantly sized product to be demonstrated on-site with no network access.  If vpn is out, then maybe gotomeeting web conference? (you can sit in your office and the customer in their bunker with minimum web connectivity): http://www.gotomeeting.com/fec/online_meeting

Comment: Is your listener configured against a 'normal' IP address or hostname/FQDN, or against `localhost` - `127.0.0.1`? If it's an address that's reliant on your adapter then it will drop out when the network does, but `localhost` shouldn't be affected by that. Of course, if you change to `localhost` then it will *only* work locally, but not sure if that's a problem, and there are solutions if it is.

Comment: I found the answer in another forum specific for the windchill product(login needed)
http://portal.ptcuser.org/p/fo/st/thread=52005&posted=1
It is related with Linux configuration to resolve the IPs:

    "Edit your /etc/resolv.conf to look like this when not connected to a network:
    
    domain local domain
    search localdomain
    nameserver 127.0.0.1"


Thank you for your prompt answers guys!!!

Comment: @GuilhermeRocha, it is encouraged on Stack Overflow to answer your own questions, if you have an answer. It sounds like you do now, so It would be nice to record it in the answer section, and not just as a comment.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance sorry about that and thank you for moderating this marvelous website!

Comment: @GuilhermeRocha, I am far from a moderator around here. Just a long time user.

Answer (score 1):

I found this tip in another forum specific for the windchill product(login needed)
http://portal.ptcuser.org/p/fo/st/thread=52005&posted=1

It is related with Linux configuration to resolve the IPs:

```
"Edit your /etc/resolv.conf to look like this when not connected to a network:

domain local domain
search localdomain
nameserver 127.0.0.1"
```

Worked perfectly!

Thank you for your prompt answers guys!!!